# Where does Crystal Report fit in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc, crystal-reports

So far I have been using only Spring MVC + Hibernate to create a web application. Also, I have some boilerplate to assist the service layer accessing the database and finally display the report or result as PDF / HTML. Should I incorporate Crystal Reports ? If I do where and how it fits in this scenario ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how Crystal Reports would fit in, as it is not for Java, and only runs on Windows.

You should look into using JasperReports, as it is similar to Crystal, and Spring has some built-in integration points:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jasper-reports

Answer (score -2):

You can use libraries of SAP to integrate crystal report in spring mvc.
http://lvtutorial.com/spring-mvc/integrate-crystal-report-in-spring-mvc.html

Get samples crystal report with version for eclipse.
http://scn.sap.com/community/crystal-reports-for-eclipse

Refer more detail as
[Export Crystal reports to PDF in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178778/export-crystal-reports-to-pdf-in-java)

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).